# Adding tabs to action bar

Tags: android

Why is this code crashing I am doing this exactly according to Google's guidelines but I am getting a null pointer exception on the line

```
 final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Here is the complete code. I am doing this exactly per Google's dev page which I have linked to here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.pager_view);  

    //TabSetup
    tabPagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }


    });

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };

    //ADD THE APP'S 3 TABS
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("News").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Surveys").setTabListener(tabListener));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Connect").setTabListener(tabListener));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that action bar tabs were deprecated with Android 5.0.

Beyond that, you probably are using a theme that does not have a native action bar, such as `Theme.AppCompat`. If you are using `appcompat-v7` with `Theme.AppCompat`, make sure that you are inheriting from `ActionBarActivity` and then use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.